# What is the ID or class for the Wizard Page name?

Tags: 8, webforms

In Webform 8 I am using the Attachment PDF / Entity Print to send a PDF of the submission via e-mail.

I am able to target the field labels, fieldset and webform-elements to add CSS but cannot find the correct ID or class for the wizard page titles.

Where do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each wizard page is rendered as details element.

Below is the Entity Print markup from the webform_example.module's 'Example: Wizard'.

```
<details 
 class="webform-container webform-container-type-details js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" 
 data-webform-element-id="example_wizard--information" 
 id="example_wizard--information"
 open="open">    
   <summary 
     role="button" 
     aria-controls="example_wizard--information" 
     aria-expanded="true" 
     aria-pressed="true">
     Your Information
     </summary>
   <div class="details-wrapper">
   ...
   </div>
</details>
```